# Xampp access forbidden after path change

Tags: apache, xampp

I changed path of my localhost in xampp from

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

To

```
#DocumentRoot "C:/test"
#<Directory "C:/test">
```

But if I try to access the localhost now `https://localhost:81/`( I am using https) I get `403 access forbidden`

Answer (score 0):

What port your Xampp is listening?

By Default it will always listen to port:80 but your's is listening to :81 So check in config file what port your xampp is listening.

Comment: It is listening to 81, It didn't work sometimes with 80 so I changed it to 81.